# How to properly get a View from a ListAdapter?

Tags: android, view, adapter, viewgroup

How do I properly use ListAdapter.getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) method?
I'm having trouble finding out what the ViewGroup expect.

From what I get:

- position is the element number that i want
- convertView is the View that I defined for the items in my layout
- parent = ?

Comment: What do you mean, "finding out the ViewGroup expect"?

Comment: what should I put in the ViewGroup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parent is the `ListView` (or other type of `ViewGroup`) whose data is being supplied by the `ListAdapter`.

Note: You shouldn't really be calling this method directly. It is an `Adapter` interface method you typically override in your own `BaseAdapter` subclass to give you complete control over how the views are displayed for each item in the list.